# Calling a method on a property

Tags: c++, oop, syntax, properties, encapsulation

I have a class that has a property named title implemented as a nested class, how can I call std::strings's methods on it ? (I am trying to make hidden encapsulation.)

```
#include <iostream>

class test {
    public:
        class {
            private :
                std::string value;

            public:
                operator const std::string & () {
                    return value;
                }

                void operator =(const std::string & source) { value = source;}
        } title;
};

int main() {
    test t;
    t.title = "title"; // this works.
    t.title.find("t"); // error here.
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221397/discussion-on-question-by-linternetsansfil-calling-a-method-on-a-property).

Comment: I think it failed because `t.title.find("t")` is trying to access the method find() of title.
But there is none. You should try : `std::string s = t.title; s.find("t");`  There may be better solution but this one is quick and simple